# Make relation between five tables to one table in SQL Server that do not refuse database normalization

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I have some tables with names Contacts, Follows, Tasks, Tickets, Accounts and ...
Each of the above tables, should have relation with Notifications table.

Now I use this structure for Notifications table in SQL to create relation between them:

```
Id, ContactId, FollowId, TaskId, TicketId, AccountId, Text
```

`Id` is the primary key and `ContactId`, `FollowId`, `TaskId`, `TicketId`, `AccountId` should be foreign keys.

Every time a record is added to this table, just one column of this foreign keys list got value, like this:

```
Id  ContactId   FollowId    TaskId  TicketId    AccountId   Text
1   null        null        null    null        2           notification test 1
2   null        null        null    12          null        notification test 2
3   null        null        null    11          null        notification test 3
4   5           null        null    null        null        notification test 4
5   null        1           null    null        null        notification test 5
6   null        null        null    null        3           notification test 6
7   null        null        null    null        43          notification test 7
```

Is this a fine architect that does not refuse Normalization in databBase?

Comment: Your fkeys seems to be pointing in the wrong direction..?

Comment: why you don't add a notificationID foreign key in each table instead? from there you can monitor each table with its notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure you created is denormalized structure not ideal for OLTP environment.

Below would be ideal normalized structure

```
Notifications Contacts
Notifications Follows
Notifications Tasks
Notifications Tickets
Notifications Accounts
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it a fine solution?  Well, not really.  But SQL doesn't have a great solution for entities (such as `notations`) that are related to a bunch of other entities.

This particular solution has the advantage that you can declare foreign key relationships.  It has the disadvantage that adding new entity types requires restructuring the table and that each of the `NULL` values occupies space.  So, it is not particularly scalable.

There are no perfect solutions.  If you are willing to give up the foreign key relationships, you can just do:

```
create table notifications (
    notificationId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    notificationType varchar(32),
    relatedId int,
    check notificationType in ('contact', . . .)
);
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not have filtered foreign key relationships.  You can do something like this:

```
create table contacts (
    contactId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    . . .
);

create table n (
      id int identity(1, 1),
      relatedId int,
      notificationType varchar(32),
      contactId as (case when type = 'contact' then relatedId end) persisted,
      foreign key (contactId) references contacts(contactId)
);
```

This almost does what you want.  The problem is that `contactId` needs to be persisted to be used in a foreign key relationship -- and persisted computed columns still occupy space.